# ADMU0509I: The Application Server "server1" cannot be reached. It appears to be stopped

Tags: server, rhel, ibm-was

I have setup a WebSphere Application Server on my RHEL 7 virtual machine. When I start the server, it starts fine and I can access the admin console but when I try to stop or get the status of  the server using the script

```
sh stopServer.sh -server1 / sh serverStatus.sh server1
```

It gives the following message,

```
ADMU0509I: The Application Server "server1" cannot be reached. It appears to be stopped.
```

My wsadmin scripts are not working, when I run the script

```
sh wsadmin.sh -user wasadmin -password Password
```

I get the following error

```
WASX7023E: Error creating "SOAP" connection to host "localhost"; exception information: com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.ConnectorNotA
vailableException: [SOAPException: faultCode=SOAP-ENV:Protocol; msg=; targetException=java.net.MalformedURLException]
WASX7213I: This scripting client is not connected to a server process; please refer to the log file /opt/IBM\WebSphere/AppServer
/profiles/AppSrv01/logs/wsadmin.traceout for additional information.
```

I can access the console on the browser without any issue.

Comment: Maybe you dont have `localhost` in your `etc/hosts` file or it points to invalid address.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on this more specifically. The file `ssl.client.props` looks like this typically around the `com.ibm.ssl.protocol` property:

```
$ grep -i tls -C 2 /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/properties/ssl.client.props
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------
com.ibm.ssl.alias=DefaultSSLSettings
com.ibm.ssl.protocol=SSL_TLS
com.ibm.ssl.securityLevel=HIGH
com.ibm.ssl.trustManager=IbmPKIX
--
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------
#com.ibm.ssl.alias=AnotherSSLSettings
#com.ibm.ssl.protocol=SSL_TLS
#com.ibm.ssl.securityLevel=HIGH
#com.ibm.ssl.trustManager=IbmX509
```

***This property can take a number of values:***

> This property is the SSL handshake protocol that is used for this SSL
>   configuration. This property attempts Transport Layer Security (TLS)
>   first, but accepts any remote handshake protocol, including SSLv3 and
>   TLSv1. Valid values for this property include SSL_TLS, SSL, SSLv2
>   (client side only), SSLv3, TLS, TLSv1, SSL_TLSv2, TLSv1.1, and
>   TLSv1.2.

***These values are described in this table:***

[image: ss of table of ssl props]

#### References

- [ssl.client.props client configuration file](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/rsec_sslclientpropsfile.html)
- [Appendix A: Protocols and Cipher Suites](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSYKE2_7.1.0/com.ibm.java.security.component.71.doc/security-component/jsse2Docs/protocols.html)

Answer (score 0):

For me this problem came when the security level of the WAS was not consistent. 
In the IBM console, it was set to TLSv1.2 and in `ssl.client.props` file it was set to SSL_TLS. Once they were changed to the same value my console could connect to WAS.